# jQuery-Lint with jQuery 1.6.2 throws many warnings which aren't useful?

Tags: jquery, firebug, jquery-lint

I found a little example for jQuery-Lint ([lint example on jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/zalun/UYpSE/)) in jsfiddle.

But, when I test this with jQuery 1.6.2, jQuery-Lint throws many (extra) warnings in firebug...

So is jQuery-Lint not useful for jQuery 1.6.2 testing?

Comment: Your fiddle is invalid, what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: This fiddle should be invalid yes (its not an example of mine) BUT if you use this with JQuery 1.6.2 JQuerylint throw also many warnings witch has nothing to do with the error. This warnings are useless and has nothing to do with the "real" error, so I wondered if you can use JQueryLint with 1.6.2 or not. To understand it just watch the consol in firebug first with JQuery 1.4.0 and after try it with 1.6.2 then you will see the difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That fiddle (and apparently jsFiddle's ***jQueryLint (edge)*** checkbox) runs a very old version of JQueryLint (version 0.34).

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UYpSE/76/), which uses [the latest release](https://github.com/jamespadolsey/jQuery-Lint), 1.01.

Comment: ok, thx for this answer. I think jsfiddle should update the JQueryLint on their page...